Filtering Google Public Patent Data in BigQuery
This is a very specific question that I'm not sure where to even ask, so I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction. But I am querying from a public patent BigQuery dataset:
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google_patents_public_datasets/google-patents-public-data?hl=en-GB&project=patents-bigquery-426719
and am trying to figure out how to filter based on a field called "Status". This field is visible on the individual pages on Google Patents (that get their data from this dataset), but I can't find the field anywhere in the dataset's schema.
Has anyone happened to have used this dataset before or know who I might reach out to to get a question like this answered?
I've tried looking through the dataset's schema and a data preview and can't find the field anywhere.

this?  SELECT DISTINCT entity_status FROM patents-public-data.patents.publications LIMIT 1000

@smoore4 I originally thought that was it too, but that seems to be something else that is not related to the "Status" that's displayed on the webpages. Are you familiar with this database? I have some other questions about it but can't figure out if there's a contact at Google that could help answer them

is it in patentsview?  i wonder if it is calculated from other fields like expiration date.
SELECT * FROM patents-public-data.patentsview.us_term_of_grant LIMIT 1000

@smoore4 I don't believe so. Sorry for the delayed response with this, but yes I am assuming they are somehow calculating it based on the terms of the patent/expiration date or something like that. Unrelated, but do you know where the images that are on each patent's Google Patent page are stored in BigQuery?  Also, is there any kind of specific support for using this dataset? (other than asking around on StackOverflow) Thanks!
